# Spring security roles and permissions

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have one project with Spring MVC and Spring Security.

Roles:

```
ROLE_USER and ROLE_ADMIN
```

Permissions:

```
READ_PRIVILEGE, WRITE_PRIVILEGE
```

And between roles and permissions:

```
ROLE_ADMIN -> READ_PRIVILEGE AND WRITE_PRIVILEGE
ROLE_USER -> READ_PRIVILEGE
```

The situation is the next:

I have one controller and I want to secure the actions with the annotation

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
```

Something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/usersAndRoles", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
public @ResponseBody String usersAndRoles(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException
```

But the annotation doesn't work, but if I change the code to something like this works ok:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/usersAndRoles", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('WRITE_PRIVILEGE')")
public @ResponseBody String usersAndRoles(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException
```

Anyone can give me a hint about this? 
I don't want to restrict the actions with permissions, I prefer the Role restriction.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you configure permissions and roles?

By default, `hasRole("role")` checkes that "role" is in GrantedAuthorities of Auththenticated user, so it should work as long as you have your role there.

Maybe you are using your permissions as GrantedAuthorities?

Comment: Yes, the problem was over the loadUserByUsername over my custom UserDetailsService. Thanks.